# JSF JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource,

Tags: jsf, primefaces, http-status-code-404

In my jsf 2 (primefaces 3) application, I designed and used a page not found (404) for any request that is not match a page. I works fine for all requests except for the jsf resources such as "jquery.js.jsf". When this resource is requested without  any query string the application is unable to find it but just return 404 as response status code and never forward the user to the page not found that I've already designed and used.

Does anybody know how can I figure this out, so that for JSF resources my application works as the other resources.

Best